# How to validate read and secure documents in CouchDB?

Tags: javascript, couchdb, nosql

In [10 Common Misconceptions about CouchDB](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKQ9kXKoHS8), Joan Touzet is asked (30:16) if CouchDB will have a way to secure/validate reads on specific documents and/or specific fields of a document.

Joan says that if someone has access to the database, he/she can access all documents in that database.

So she says that there are a few ways to accomplish that:

1. (30:55) Cloudant was working on field level security access. Have they implemented it yet? Is it open-sourced?
2. (32:10) You should create separate document in a separate database.
3. (32:20) Filtered replications. She mentions that it slows 'things' down. She means that the filter slows the replication, correct?

Also, according to rcouch wiki (https://github.com/rcouch/rcouch/wiki/Validate-documents-on-read), it implements a `validate_doc_read` function (I haven't tested it, though). Does CouchDB has anything like it?

As far as I can see, the best approach is to model the database according to my problem (one database for this, another for that, one for this person, another for that person) and do filtered replications when necessary. Any suggestions?